# register consuming function using .then

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm new to JS, just a question on promise. Let's say we have the following code:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   ... //producing code
   resolve('This is my resolved data');
});

promise.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

so when the promise is created, this executor function runs automatically.
but what happen if the producing code finishes very quickly and before the .then is registered? isn't that it is too late to register .then with our completion function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 25.6.5.4.1 of the ECMA spec defines `Promise.prototype.then`s behaviour as:

> [...]
>
> 7. If promise.[[PromiseState]] is "pending" "pending", then
>
>    a. Append fulfillReaction as the last element of the List that is promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]].
>
>    b. Append rejectReaction as the last element of the List that is promise.[[PromiseRejectReactions]].
> 8. Else if promise.[[PromiseState]] is "fulfilled" "fulfilled", then
>
>    a. Let value be promise.[[PromiseResult]].
>
>    b. Perform EnqueueJob("PromiseJobs" "PromiseJobs", PromiseReactionJob, « fulfillReaction, value »).

So if you attach `.then` callbacks to a Promise (named "fullfillReaction" and "rejectReaction" here) and the promise did not resolve yet, the callbacks will be stored to be called back later (7a&b).

If the Promise already resolved by the time already (8), then it will directly create a job to call back the callback (8b) that will be executed nearly immeadiately (at the next microtick¹).

> isn't that it is too late to register .then with our completion function?

No, it isn't too late. The Promise still knows the value it resolved to, and will call back the `.then` callback with that nearly immeadiately.

By example:

```
  const promise = new Promise((resolve) => { // A promise gets created and is in "pending" state
   setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("value"); // the promise gets turned into "fullfilled" state, and "value" will be stored in the internal PromiseResult property of the promise
    }, 1000);
  });

  // By now the promise did not resolve yet, "callback" will be stored internally
  promise.then(function callback() { /*...*/ });

  // one second later, the promise fullfills and "callback" gets called. The promise is in "fullfilled" state

 setTimeout(() => { // another second later, this runs
   // As the promise is fullfilled already, "callback2" will directly put into a job onto the promise microtask queue
   promise.then(function callback2() {
     console.log("callback2 called");
   });
   // ...then the line below will run
   console.log("then attached after 2s");
   // at this point, synchronous code finishes, the call stack unwinds
   // the engine will continue working on the microtask queue
   // and voíla, it'll find the "callback2" callback, and will call it with the promises result (so it gets executed "nearly immeadiately")

 }, 2000);
```

---

¹: Thats just to guarantee that `.then(...)` will always run in an "asynchronous" way. For the sake of simplicity you could just say that the function gets run directly.

Comment: do you mean if Promise already resolved before .then, the promise will create a job and wait for .then to register callback function?

Comment: @slowjams, no, if the promise resolved it will set its internal state to "fullfilled" and will store the result internally. Then if you attach a `.then`, it'll call back the `.then(callback)` nearly immeadiately (a Job is the thing that goes onto the event queue (google "event queue JS" to find some great tutorials))

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how long the delay on resolve/reject calls is - it could be instantaneous for that matter - but `then` and `catch` still work because it's still a Promise:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('This is my resolved data');
});

promise.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I know it doesn't matter how long the delay on resolve/reject calls is, but why it doesn't matter, what does it make it work?

Comment: @slowjams Because it's a Promise.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter as Promise will execute its success or failure parameters of method then if then is registered on Promise.

`in order to check:`

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//    ... //producing code
   resolve('This is my resolved data');
});

// it will execute after a second
setTimeout(() => {
    promise.then((data) => {
       console.log(" asdasda", data);
    });
}, 1000)

promise.then((data) => {
    console.log("asdada asdasda", data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded language with event loop. So there is no such condition as

> producing code finishes very quickly and before the .then is
>   registered

When you create a promise, you create just an object. That object has knowledge of state, resolve and reject conditions of the promise. 
And resolved state of a promise will be kept in the same promise object. Which means, if you register a handler to promise, which was already resolved, you'd still get the resolved value. Because it's stored in promise object.

Check the example below:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('resolver function')
    setTimeout(() => resolve('This is my resolved data'), 1000)
});

console.log('just before adding promise handler')

promise.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
    
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('just before adding a late promise handler')

    promise.then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Disagree to the first part (or it is at least missleading). For sure you can create two asynchronous tasks, one resolving the promise and one attaching a `.then` callback. If the first finishes before the second, the `.then` gets attached after the promise resolved.